# Does Holy Symbol Expertise mean all enemies, or just the ones you actually attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, cleric, holy-symbol

Does the `Holy Symbol Expertise` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3565)] ... *cannot gain combat advantage* ... apply to all enemies, or just the ones you actually attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It applies to all enemies.**

> When you attack an enemy with an implement attack using a holy symbol, your enemies cannot gain combat advantage against you until the start of your next turn,

"An enemy" followed by "your enemies".

It seems pretty clear to me that it is intended for one attack to grant you protection against all.

Comment: ouch! If it's any enemy at all, this seems a seriously overpowered Expertise !! ... `Master at Arms` allows you to sheath/draw in one minor as opposed to two, `Axe Expertise` lets you re-roll a 1 on the one damage dice ... this eliminates ALL combat advantage, so no Rogue damage, etc. ... only option I can see is the monsters ready attack which trigger in the players turn, as the power is "until the start of your next turn"

Comment: @SteveC no the scenario you describe would not work as you cannot delay or ready to avoid a condition like this. However, while it might be slightly overpowered its not significantly.

Comment: @waxeagle Why can't somebody ready an attack which is potentially triggered in the players turn? Delaying works fine, unless the player again uses Holy Symbol Expertise to negate CA

Comment: @SteveC no, neither delaying nor readying can be used to escape time delimited effects. if its in effect at the start of your turn I don't believe you can delay to avoid it.

Comment: @waxeagle I think we're talking at cross-purposes ... during the players turn, they attack with holy symbol and so get the CA effect. Monster readies an attack to trigger on "something" the players does. Next players turn, first thing is the CA effect ends, then they do the "something" and so trigger the monsters readied action, which because it's an immediate interrupt goes before anything the players can do, including another attack to get the CA effect.

Comment: @SteveC, maybe y'all need another question?

Comment: @patludwig Good idea